# Angular 7 - generate URL from an angular component

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to Angular and come from a django background. I am interested in generating a url using an angular component name. For example, in django we use something like reverse('login'), this when executed will return the url '/login'. Is there any way to do this in  Angular 7 ? I find doing the following can be an issue and want to avoid it:

this.router.navigate(['/login']);

If tomorrow, I change the endpoint, I will have to change it in each place it has been mentioned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can define a constant and use it everywhere instead of hardcoding the array every time.

Comment: That is always the option, however, is there is a standard Angular way to do this?